# Was the U.S. planning an invasion of Afghanistan before 9/11?

Tags: united-states, afghanistan, war-on-terror

Some sources seem to indicate that the U.S. was planning a military attack against Afghanistan before September 11.

> Niaz Naik, a former Pakistani Foreign Secretary, was told by senior American officials in mid-July that military action against Afghanistan would go ahead by the middle of October.
>
> - Armey, George. (2001, September 18). [US 'planned attack on Taleban'](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/south_asia/1550366.stm). *BBC*.
>
> The day before the September 11 attacks, the Bush administration agreed on a plan to oust the Taliban regime in Afghanistan by force if it refused to hand over Osama bin Laden, according to a report by a bipartisan commission of inquiry.
>
> - Borger, Julian. (2004, March 24). [Bush team 'agreed plan to attack the Taliban the day before September 11'](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2004/mar/24/september11.usa2). *The Guardian*.
>
> in August 2001. Central Asian affairs representative Christina Rocca and a coterie of State Department officials voiced disgust and issued a threat to the Taliban ambassador: "Accept our offer of a carpet of gold, or we bury you under a carpet of bombs." Bush promptly informed Pakistan and India that the US would launch a military mission against Afghanistan before the end of October.
>
> - Chin, Larry. (2002, March 10). [Players on a rigged grand chessboard: Bridas, Unocal and the Afghanistan pipeline](https://web.archive.org/web/20020320025837/http://onlinejournal.com/Special_Reports/Chin031002/chin031002.html). *Online Journal*.

However, when I skim Richard A. Clarke's accounts, it seems like the Bush administration was focused on Iraq and was disinterested in Afghanistan.

It seems clear enough that the U.S. was planning an invasion of Iraq before 9/11:

- Borger. (2004). [Bush decided to remove Saddam 'on day one'](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2004/jan/12/usa.books). *The Guardian*.
- Behan, Richard W. (2008/2016). [The Fraudulent War](https://web.archive.org/web/20170328112541/https://d3n8a8pro7vhmx.cloudfront.net/codepink/pages/8965/attachments/original/1480519899/TheFraudulentWar.pdf?1480519899). (adapted to [HTML at *CounterPunch*](https://www.counterpunch.org/2016/12/15/george-w-bushs-criminal-wars-of-aggression-a-detailed-history/))
- Stein & Dickenson. (2006). [Lie by Lie: A Timeline of How We Got Into Iraq](https://www.motherjones.com/politics/2011/12/leadup-iraq-war-timeline/). *Mother Jones*.
- Behan. (2008). [The Story Behind George Bush’s Lies](https://www.counterpunch.org/2008/07/01/the-story-behind-george-bush-s-lies/). *Counterpunch*.

### Questions

1. **What was the status of preparations and approval of U.S. military action against Afghanistan (if any) before 9/11?**
2. Was the U.S. only considering sporadic bombing in Afghanistan, or were an invasion or regime change efforts being considered?
3. At what level were these plans approved?
4. Was a particular timeline in place for implementation as Naik claims?

Comment: The Military make hundreds of contingency plans as a matter of course, so I'd be surprised if they didn't have plans to invade random countries. Of course whether they expect to use them is another matter.

Comment: The OP is not referring to contingency plans, that should be obvious from the question.

Comment: @Joe: But the writers of those articles may well have mistaken those contingency plans for actual intent, or - given political motivations - deliberately used their existence to delude their readers into believing there was actual intent.  See the oft-repeated claim of US plans to invade Britain post-WWI.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the archives needed to answer won't be available for decades (unless the US declassifies them before that for some odd reason).

Comment: @jamesqf I respectfully disagree.  While those three quotes may be wrong, I have no idea of the veracity, the phrasing is in absolutes and not contingency plans.  "would go ahead" not "may go ahead", "the Bush administration agreed on a plan" not "looked at plans", "Bush promptly informed Pakistan and India that the US would launch a military mission against Afghanistan before the end of October".  Sounds very absolute to me.

Comment: @Joe: Whichever it is doesn't really matter. The question probably won't get a definite answer with supporting sources in our lifetime.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy I agree that it would be very hard if not impossible to prove one way or another beyond a shadow of a doubt.  This question should probably be closed.  However, I wanted to support the OPs question, which would be very different if he were posting quotes of contingency plans.

Comment: @Joe: From where I'm standing you're arguing with two commenters who agree with you. Simon stated the obvious problem with the question. And James merely answered you to point out that the sources quoted by OP could very well have spun hypotheticals out of proportion. Yes, the OP is asking about absolutes, but then quotes sources which could have turned molehills into mountains.

Comment: From the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_invasion_of_Afghanistan): _A change in US policy was effected in August 2001.  ... A meeting of top national security officials agreed that the Taliban would be presented with an ultimatum to hand over bin Laden and other al-Qaeda operatives. If the Taliban refused, the US would provide covert military aid to anti-Taliban groups. If both those options failed, "the deputies agreed that the United States would seek to overthrow the Taliban regime through more direct action_."

Comment: @justCal And the other source in that section of the article appears to be Steve Coll's [Ghost Wars](https://archive.org/details/isbn_9780141020808/page/n11).  In any event, the Wikipedia article appears to answer the question in the title, and also most of the elements in the body of the question.

Comment: Yes, although the wiki article conveniently leaves out the part about the probable three years worth of other efforts before getting to the *direct action* part.

Comment: @justCal I think it is implicit. "_If the Taliban refused, the US would provide covert military aid to anti-Taliban groups_".  That phase would certainly take years.  And only then, after "_both those options failed_" would the US "_seek to overthrow the Taliban regime through more direct action_".

Comment: @sempaiscuba: The Wikipedia article doesn't even begin to address Naik's claim that the U.S. was planning military action against Afghanistan with an intended timeline for implementation. I would appreciate any assistance modifying this question to be more clear.

Comment: @sondra.kinsey The best advice I can give is to read that section of the Wikipedia article, perhaps even quoting it in your question, and then **be very specific** about what parts of the claims you think don't match. FWIW, as far as I can see, Naik's claim appears to broadly match the statement in the Wikipedia article.about "_covert military aid to anti-Taliban groups_" if the Taliban didn't give up Bin Laden.

Answer (score 0):

The US military did have and used the plans to invade Afghanistan drawn up prior to 911.  It’s not so nefarious as you might think however cause the US military also has plans to invade Canada,  Mexico,  and many other countries for which an invasion would be unthinkable.   These are not hypothetical plans either but very detailed plans.  The US military even has plans for a [zombie ‍♀️ apocalypse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CONOP_8888).   Literally!

Why?  Two reasons, Because good planners require practice.  Secondarily you never know what the future will bring.  The plans to invade Afghanistan where drawn up in an age when the Soviet Union had invaded and got bogged there.  It would have been the last place an American administration would seek adventure.  Yet after 911 the plan went into effect.  Extraordinarily!

The plan incidentally was to use minimal military footprint and rather to send representatives with money to buy support.   During the Bush administration which executed the invasion there were fewer American soldiers in Afghanistan than police officers in Manhattan island.  Good plan.

The pentagon defends spending money on a zombie invasion plan by suggesting that components of the plan could be used for more realistic threats.  As well as the training benefits.

Comment: That is clearly not what is inquired here. The question is not about a hypothetical scenario but concrete plans and short- or mid-term intentions on way to realisation. As in: without 911, US would have stilll invaded anyway, as plan outlined in docX (well, or not really, if A to Q is 'no, only hypothetical war game like', as you *may* want to imply here?)

Comment: @justCal Even Amazon have contingencies for the _Zombie Apocalypse_.  It's written into their [Terms & Conditions](https://aws.amazon.com/service-terms/) for Amazon Web Services (see clause 57.10).

Comment: @LangLangC For context, see my comments on the question above.

Comment: @LangLangC  there is nothing hypothetical about US invasion plans.  They are written, studied, discussed, and graded rewritten and argued over as well as reviewed on a periodic schedule.  Again if they weren’t detailed what possible value would they have as an exercise   It’s really what a peacetime military does isn’t it,  prepare and plan for war.  Training war planners is an important discipline of peacetime militaries as is preparing and thinking of the unthinkable.

Comment: @LangLangC   Likewise not hypothetically in the case of Afghanistan the “invasion” plan did predate 911.  It was written up by a US Military studying the mistakes of the Soviet invasion which then asked itself how would we do it differently.

Comment: @sempaiscuba To me, this is the equivalent of 'a sensitive topic'. Most conspiracy theories use these vague sources and the like to prove that "invasion was already scheduled for *the date,* but approval (of fly-over states, like Missouri, France or Pakistan) was lacking (hence some action for justification needed to be orchestrated, or came in handy). Whether or not OP is motivated by *that*, imo: this Q needs A that addresses *which* plans, for what, when, with *what  level of realisation potential and schedule* to not trigger the traps. Very concrete, very reliable sources, contextualised.

Comment: @LangLangC Actually, unless and until it explicitly addresses what more the OP wants that is not already in the Wikipedia article, I'd probably argue that the question should be closed as _too basic_.  Otherwise, it is likely to attract exactly exactly those kinds of conspiracy theorists.  But in the end, that is a community decision.